# Tf-idf match list vs list, instead of one list

Tags: python, string-matching, tf-idf

I'm experimenting with tf-idf matching. I followed the tutorial from [this](https://bergvca.github.io/2017/10/14/super-fast-string-matching.html) article. I would like to know if I can match an input list versus another list of already processed data and then get this script to return the output as potential matches from the existing second list for every item of the input list.

I hope one of you guys can put me in the right direction! Thanks!!

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
names = pd.read_csv('sample-data/descriptions_1.csv')


import re
def ngrams(string, n=4):
    string = re.sub(r'[,-./]|\sBD', r'', str(string))
    ngrams = zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return [''.join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

company_names = names['name']
comparer_names = comparer['name']
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, analyzer=ngrams)
tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(company_names)

import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import sparse_dot_topn.sparse_dot_topn as ct


def awesome_cossim_top(A, B, ntop, lower_bound=0):
    # force A and B as a CSR matrix.
    # If they have already been CSR, there is no overhead
    A = A.tocsr()
    B = B.tocsr()
    M, _ = A.shape
    _, N = B.shape

    idx_dtype = np.int32

    nnz_max = M * ntop

    indptr = np.zeros(M + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)
    indices = np.zeros(nnz_max, dtype=idx_dtype)
    data = np.zeros(nnz_max, dtype=A.dtype)

    ct.sparse_dot_topn(
        M, N, np.asarray(A.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
        np.asarray(A.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
        A.data,
        np.asarray(B.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
        np.asarray(B.indices, dtype=idx_dtype),
        B.data,
        ntop,
        lower_bound,
        indptr, indices, data)

    return csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(M, N))

import time
t1 = time.time()
matches = awesome_cossim_top(tf_idf_matrix, tf_idf_matrix.transpose(), 30, 0.5)
t = time.time()-t1
print("SELFTIMED:", t)


def get_matches_df(sparse_matrix, name_vector, top=100):
    non_zeros = sparse_matrix.nonzero()

    sparserows = non_zeros[0]
    sparsecols = non_zeros[1]

    if top:
        nr_matches = top
    else:
        nr_matches = sparsecols.size

    left_side = np.empty([nr_matches], dtype=object)
    right_side = np.empty([nr_matches], dtype=object)
    similairity = np.zeros(nr_matches)

    for index in range(0, nr_matches):
        left_side[index] = name_vector[sparserows[index]]
        right_side[index] = name_vector[sparsecols[index]]
        similairity[index] = sparse_matrix.data[index]

    return pd.DataFrame({'left_side': left_side,
                         'right_side': right_side,
                         'similairity': similairity})

matches_df = get_matches_df(matches, company_names, top=1000)
matches_df = matches_df[matches_df['similairity'] < 0.99999] # Remove all exact matches
print(matches_df.sample(20))

file_name = str("hallo.csv")
matches_df.to_csv(file_name, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem with a few modifications to the approach you link to in [this article](https://bergvca.github.io/2017/10/14/super-fast-string-matching.html). The key is to make the following modification:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, analyzer=ngrams)
first_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(first_lines)
second_idf_matrix = vectorizer.transform(second_lines)
matches = awesome_cossim_top(first_idf_matrix, second_idf_matrix, 1, 0)
```

This means that the function `get_matches_df` is no longer useful, instead to extract the matching line for each line in the first list, we do the following:

```
for dirty_idx, _ in enumerate(first_lines):
    second_idx = matches[dirty_idx].argmax()
```

Comment: I think you need to change `first_idx` to `dirty_idx`.